# Is Bloomberg Open API really free and able to get the real time market data?

Tags: java, bloomberg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bloomberg Open API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api)

According to the document in Bloomberg Open Website:
http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

Does Everyone have ability to get the real-time market data by using the Bloomberg Open API at no cost and without Bloomberg Terminal?

Why can I run the sample code "SimpleSubscriptionExample.java" provided by Bloomberg?

Here is some code:

```
String serverHost = "127.0.0.1";
int serverPort = 8194;
String serviceName = "//blp/mktdata";

SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.setServerHost(serverHost);
sessionOptions.setServerPort(serverPort);
```

Since I don't know the serverHost, how can I get to the Bloomberg through Open API?

Comment: I think they've opened up the API, not the actual data. In particular, from http://www.bloomberg.com/pressroom/2012/01/31/bloomberg-opens-its-data-distribution-technology/index.html: "* Bloomberg is offering its programming interface (BLPAPI) under a free-use agreement. This does not apply to any content."

Comment: @Simon Nickerson thanks for notice :-)