# bloomberg api server?

Tags: api, bloomberg

looking at bloomberg api 
http://www.openbloomberg.com/
and downloaded example code, looks we need some server to get the data?

```
private void run(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String serverHost = "127.0.0.1";
    int serverPort = 8194;
    String serviceName = "//blp/mktdata";

    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
    sessionOptions.setServerHost(serverHost);
    sessionOptions.setServerPort(serverPort);
```

are the servers freely available or we need to buy that?

if not, this means we still do not have a open free data (either live or historical?)

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1"` is your local machine and you need to have a Bloomberg terminal open & logged on (=> you need to be a subscriber, which is chargeable).

The only thing that is "free" is the API, which has been open sourced. But the data remains proprietary, whether it's live or historical.

Comment: thx....so this seems not an option for me now, do you have any good suggestion for good source for live data? google has deprecated financial api, now i'm using yahoo..

Comment: @hetaoblog I use Bloomberg so I would not know what other feed to recommend, having not tried them.

Answer (score 1):

There's relevant information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api) SO post. Specifically [user2023861](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023861/user2023861) offers a project [Bloomberg API Emulator](http://bemu.codeplex.com/) which you might find useful. I haven't tried it. Bloomberg, in response to a question sent to open-tech@bloomberg.net, has announced a plan to release their own emulator later this month. The intention to do this is mentioned [here](http://www.openbloomberg.com/faq/) in the response to question 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can access some data from the bloomberg website, e.g. historical data on investment funds. It's not an officially released API so my change in the future, but for now it's working. [Here you can find a simple example to download yearly time series.](http://freeconnection.blogspot.hu/2013/09/correlation-of-investment-founds-python.html)