# Google script using newly opened bloomberg data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, bloomberg

Bloomberg is opening its market data for everyone.

http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

I'm using google spreadsheets and I was wondering if and how I can use Google script to link up with their API if possible. The bloomberg API supports c/c++, .net, java, perl, python.

Does anybody know if it is possible or how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably feasible technically, but:

- you still need to subscribe to Bloomberg to get the data (the API needs a logged in Bloomberg terminal or a Bloomberg Server to function)
- since google spreadsheets are "in the cloud", that would very likely be a breach of the Bloomberg contract, which basically forbids to use the data outside the computer where the Bloomberg terminal is installed*.

<sub>* IANAL</sub>

Comment: i'm more interested in the technically feasible part and how it would actually work.

Comment: I guess you could expose the API via a web service.

Comment: But once again only the API has been opened, the data is not available if you are not a subscriber (i.e. pay $,1,500 a month or so). And exposing it via a web service is most likely illegal.

Comment: http://www.bloomberg.com/pressroom/bloomberg-opens-its-data-distribution-technology/  It says explicitly that, "Bloomberg is opening its market data interfaces for use by technology professionals globally, without cost or restriction, the company announced today." Now as a subscriber, you already get the API that goes with excel and other. Am I miss understanding what "opening" means?

Comment: @jason_cant_code If you understand it as "you will get data for free", then yes it is a misunderstanding. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api

Comment: ok helpful. I know bloomberg isn't going to giving away the farm, but i thought they might provide some basic delayed pricing information like google and yahoo for free, then upsell customers into real time and other data. i guess i was mistaken.

Comment: @jason_cant_code No it's not the case. When you use the API, the first thing you need to do is to connect to their service, and you need valid credentials to do that.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the clarity. I see you have experience in using it.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look at the link, it doesn't look like there is a REST API available. So, you can't use Apps Scripts to fetch data.

If a REST API were made available, you can use UrlFetch class to get information.