# Python-Bloomberg Open API: Are there any examples?

Tags: python, bloomberg

I searched everywhere, including here, for an answer regarding the [bloomberg open API](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/) for Python.
I have two questions regarding this:
1. Is the historical data, such as historical prices, given for free?
2. If So, where can I find examples regarding how to retrieve this data? I tried to use [pybbg](https://github.com/bpsmith/pybbg) but didn't manage to work with it. Also, the [Bloomberg developers guide](http://www.openbloomberg.com/files/2013/04/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf) doesn't include Python guidelines.

Comment: Not sure you get any data for free. They give you the API for free to use with your (paid) subscription. It states this on the page your first link goes to in the 'note:' paragraph

Comment: Also, they have a support staff (open-tech@bloomberg.net) paid to answer such questions.

Comment: Quantopian and it's python package zipline might be a nice free pythonic alternative to bloomberg

Comment: The zipfile containing the python package contains a few examples, if they are not sufficient maybe you should try to contact them.

Comment: The data is definitely not for free - unless you subsribe to the Bloomberg data, you won't be able to retrieve anything using their API. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api

Answer (score 5):

If you download the installer and install it from 
http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

There is a folder called examples within the Python folder with example *.py files
NoAdmin_DesktopAPI_SDK\API\APIv3\Python\v3.5.5\examples

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Bloomberg API Libraries](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/) and download the zip file instead of the "self-extracting".

By the time of this post, you're able to [download it directly from here](http://static.bloomberglabs.com/api/python/blpapi_python_3.5.5.zip).

Extract the files and you'll find a folder named "examples". Enjoy!