# Using Bloomberg API in c#?

Tags: c#, bloomberg

I want to fetch changing currency rates frequently like [Current rates of GBP, EUR, JPY in comparison to USD or specified Currency.]. I googled and got Bloomberg API dotnet examples from Bloomberg's Site. But I am having problems with impementation and I do have couple of questions.

1. Do I need some sort of Bloomberg licence?
2. Can somebody tell where to start with these [API examples](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/)?

Comment: I'd be hardpressed to believe that they give their information away for free. Did you do any research on that?

Comment: What do you mean "those[API examples] samples"?

Comment: @DanielKelley: i meant "Examples on bloomberg's site". http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

Comment: You really need to explain your problem more clearly. What does "but didn't get installed" mean?

Comment: DLL's usually can be linked to in a .NET project through References, so there is no need to install it e.g. to the GAC. In the `Solution Explorer` right-click the `References` for your project and select `Add Reference...` and browse to the DLL to add it.

Comment: There is some more info about using Bloomberg API in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097382/bloomberg-open-api)

Answer (score 5):

Your first question is answered on the page you linked:

> NOTE: Bloomberg is offering this programming interface (BLPAPI) under
>   a free-use license. This license does not include nor provide access
>   to any Bloomberg data or content. If you wish to use this API to
>   access Bloomberg data, you will need a Bloomberg service subscription,
>   and should contact the nearest Bloomberg sales office in your region.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Bloomberg License otherwise you wont be able to query the Bloomberg Data Center which handles requests from the Bloomberg API.

There is a Bloomberg Emulator at https://bemu.codeplex.com/

I have not used it but it might be worth a look.

Go to the Bloomberg API website at

http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

check out the API developers guide, there are plenty of examples there.

Hope that helps.